# Local declaration of " " hides instance and Incomplete implementation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender {
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

@synthesize torque, horsepower, rpm, rpmf2;

-(IBAction)Operation1:(id)sender {
  float result = 2 * 3.14 *([torque.text floatValue] * [rpm.text floatValue]) / 33000;

  answer1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", result];
}

-(IBAction)Operation2:(id)sender {
  float result = 2 * 3.14 * ([horsepower.text floatValue] * [rpmf2.text floatValue]) /     33000;

  answer2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", result];
}
```

I want to format my text field to a number. This works but it has caution signs over my implantation answer1.text and answer2.text. The problem is that a thread point will break eventually. What is wrong with this?

EDIT:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        float result;
        IBOutlet UILabel *answer1;
        IBOutlet UILabel *answer2;
        IBOutlet UITextField *torque;
        IBOutlet UITextField *rpm;
        IBOutlet UITextField *horsepower;
        IBOutlet UITextField *rpmf2;
        int currentOperation1;
        float torque1;
        float rpm1;
        float horsepower1;
        float rpm1f2;
        float answer5;
    }

    -(IBAction)Operation1:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)Operation2:(id)sender;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *torque;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *rpm;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *horsepower;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *rpmf2;
    -(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton;
@end
```

Comment: And we need all your variable declarations.

Comment: What do the warnings say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Local Declaration Hides Instance Variable

The first error is because you have a member variable declared as

```
float result;
```

and then within your methods you have a local variable declared as the same. Therefore the local variable is masking the member variable. You should make sure the names do not collide.

## Incomplete implementation

The second error is because you have a method declared as in your header

```
-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender
```

but then you implement

```
-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton;
```

These are two entirely different methods one is called `ReturnKeyButton` and the other is called `ReturnKeyButton:` notice the colon at then end of the name.

To fix this just make sure the declarations match e.g. change

`-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton;` to `-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender` in the implementation

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been working on this for school and this is my fist true coding.  I've been staring at this for hours trying think of what I did wrong  This makes complete sense thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains two Warning messages :

**1. Local declaration of “ ” hides instance**

You have a property of ivar and a method having same name.

e.g. in your class you have a property called `myProperty` and in a method you create `myProperty`.

One way would be use a different name for your method's variable. or in the synthesize override your property with an alias as `@synthesize myProperty=_myProperty;`.

# You have `float result` in class and also in your methods. Change result to tempResult or any other variable name in both the methods `Operation1:` and `Operation2:`

*If you are using XCode 4.4+, then the compiler  `synthesize`s the properties with `_`.*

**2. Incomplete implementation - need fresh**

You have not implemented all the methods that you have declared in your .h files.

# You have not implemented `-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton;` in your .m file

You have created a local method there `-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:`

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    
    float result;
    IBOutlet UILabel *answer1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *answer2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *torque;
    IBOutlet UITextField *rpm;
    IBOutlet UITextField *horsepower;
    IBOutlet UITextField *rpmf2;
    int currentOperation1;
    float torque1;
    float rpm1;
    float horsepower1;
    float rpm1f2;
    float answer5;
    
}
What am I missin?

Comment: -(IBAction)Operation1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Operation2:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *torque;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *rpm;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *horsepower;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *rpmf2;
-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton;
@end

Comment: What implementation am i missing?  This is everything in my .h file

Comment: @CodyKollmann Your `ReturnKeyButton` method has one parameter in the header and no parameter in the implementation. If you unfold the warning in the XCode issue navigator, you will see what methods are missing.

Comment: One warning is from float.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you.  This is the first time i am using xCode and am learning.  This will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not calling the variables using self.

try calling like this

self.torque.text,
self.horsepower.text,
self.rpm.text,
self.rpmf2.text

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: This would not account for the warnings the user is seeing and your proposal should not have any effect, as the OP is currently just grabbing the ivars directly without going through accessors - which should work fine