# 'hides instance variable' warning at UIButton definition

Tags: ios, uibutton, cgrect

I am programmatically adding a UIButton to a datePicker:

```
 //today button
 CGRect todayButtonFrame = CGRectMake(180.0, 200.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 UIButton *todayButtonDatePicker = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:todayButtonFrame];
 [todayButtonDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [todayButtonDatePicker setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"today.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview: todayButtonDatePicker];
```

However, the compiler is giving me a warning:

```
Local declaration of 'todayButtonDatePicker' hides instance variable
```

Comment: Presumably `todayButtonDatePicker` is a property that you have synthesized? Show where else it's defined.

Comment: Yes @Wain, I have synthesized it and declared its property also in the header file....

Comment: @Wain, I have done the same with a UILabel, and no warning is shown.

Comment: @mvasco Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339092/local-declaration-of-hides-instance-and-incomplete-implementation

Comment: Why are you giving a local variable the same name as some property -- do you want to confuse yourself?  Maybe you meant to assign to the property instead of declaring a local variable.  If you really want a local variable, avoid confusing yourself by using a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `UIButton` as a property, do this:

```
 //today button
 CGRect todayButtonFrame = CGRectMake(180.0, 200.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 self.todayButtonDatePicker = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:todayButtonFrame];
 [self.todayButtonDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomFunction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.todayButtonDatePicker setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"today.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [self.view addSubview: self.todayButtonDatePicker];
```

Alternatively you can remove the property and just use a local variable.

Comment: Thank you, what I need is to remove the button from the superView on another method. Could I remove it using your proposal?

Comment: Yes, just call `[self.todayButtonDatePicker removeFromSuperview]`.